# I am trying to get ether mac address it is in the second column

Tags: linux, shell, ethernet, mac-address

```
ifconfig | grep ether | cut -d " " -f 10
```

This is how I am trying to get the ether but I am on this for about 2 hours trying to understand why I am selecting 10th column to cut out when ether is on 2nd column.

I'm just trying to understand

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ifconfig | grep ether | sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//g' | cut -d " " -f 2
```

This will remove leading whitespace as per this [SO-link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29760717/319826) and then you can use a single space as delimiter.

Comment: Oh that's very cool, What I understood is that when I'm trying to get mac address from my code above, -f 10 is after 10 " "(blankspace) comes actual mac and this is its colomn.

Comment: You can take the blanc space and copy it into echo and pipe it to wc (word-count) `echo "       " |  wc`. This will show you how many characters the space is. But it is more reliable to delete any whitespace in front so you know first letter is a non-whitespace.